# Can't remove instances of a class

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, pgzero

I starting to code in python and using pyzero to make a simple game. After the end of the game, I want to delete all the existing instances of certain types of classes, to allow the game to start again. I have a list of all the instances of that class, but using remove(self) seems to cause a problem in the logic that I can't work out.

```
class Ball(Actor):
    ball_list = []

    def __init__(self, actor):               
        Actor.initiate_actor(self,"ball")
        Ball.ball_list.append(self)
        self.alive = True

    def kill(self):
        if self.alive:
            self.alive = False
            Ball.ball_list.remove(self) 


def new_game():
    global game_over, score

    for actor in Ball.ball_list:
        actor.kill()

    score = 0
    game_over = False


def draw():
    global game_over
    if game_over:
        screen.clear()
        screen.draw.text("Game Over", center = (WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), color = 'white')

    else:
        screen.clear()
        backdrop.draw()  
        for actor in Ball.ball_list:
            if actor.alive:
                actor.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you remove objects from a list while you iterate through the list. Read [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), for more information about this topic.

Create a shallow copy of the list (`Ball.ball_list[:]`, see [More on Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)) and iterate trough the copy of the list, while you remove items from the original list:

```py
def new_game():
    global game_over, score

    for actor in Ball.ball_list[:]:
        actor.kill()

    score = 0
    game_over = False
```

Anyway, since you want to remove all elements from the list it is sufficient to call `clear()`

```py
Ball.ball_list.clear()
```

or to delete all the elements (see [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-del-stmt))

```py
del Ball.ball_list[:]
```

respectively to create a new and empty list

```py
Ball.ball_list = []
```

Note, the memory of objects which are not used is freed by the [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-garbage-collection), thus it is sufficient to remove an object from (all) lists. Furthermore, it is not necessary to *reset* atributes  of objects which will be destroyed.